# SQLite autoincrement regex

Tags: regex, sqlite

I am taking create statement queries from SQLite like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [users] ([id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, [username] VARCHAR, [password] VARCHAR, [default_project] VARCHAR)
```

created by using

```
SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = :table
```

and determining the autoincrement field with a regular expression like this:

```
/\b\[?id\]?\s+INTEGER\s+PRIMARY\s+KEY\s+AUTOINCREMENT\b/Ui
```

the problem is that there are different acceptable ways to write keywords such as `"id"`, `` `id` ``, `'id'`. Shown here http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

I wanted to create a regular expression that would explicitly check for these different variations...with some help of others I have gotten to this:

```
$pattern = "/\b\"(id)|(\"id\")|(\[id\])|(`id`)|('id')\"\s+INTEGER\s+PRIMARY\s+KEY\s+AUTOINCREMENT\b/Ui";
```

however there are a couple problems with this...one being that the `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` is no longer checked for...and that `('id')` isn't being matched properly...however if I were to swap its place with the `("id")`...than it would work and `("id")` wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
/(\"id\"|\[id\]|\'id\'|`id`|\\bid)\s+INTEGER\s+PRIMARY\s+KEY\s+AUTOINCREMENT/Ui
```

seems to work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

`[id]` doesn't match `[id]` but only `i` and `d`, what you're searching for is probably:

```
$pattern = "/\s(\"[a-z]+\"|\[[a-z]+\]|'[a-z]+'|[a-z]+)\s+INTEGER\s+PRIMARY\s+KEY\s+AUTOINCREMENT/Ui";
```

using `[a-z]+` so that you can match any alphabetic field name and then find it in the first match (also notice that there can be rowids that don't use the `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword: they're both valid but with a [slightly different meaning](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)).